# Complex IIS URL Rewrite

Tags: iis, redirect, rewrite

I've beat my head against Google trying to get this to work, but I suppose I just don't fully understand the rewrite engine or I stink at regex. Here's my scenario, though.

I'm using IIS 7.5 with URL Rewrite installed. I have access to the web.config file. Let's say the actual server name (locally and in DNS) is authoritative.domain.subdomain.com. It has a CNAME of cname.domain.subdomain.com. I want to do a number of things:

- Enforce https
- Redirect all requests to cname.domain.subdomain.com (even partial/non-FQDN such as authoritative, authoritative.domain, or cname.domain)
- If the request is for the root site, append /subfolder

Try as I might, I can get each of these rules to work on their own, but I cannot get them all to work when enabled together. Note again that this is IIS (I have no choice), so that may complicate things.

Thanks for your help!